# Locus of trirectangular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, 3d, locus

Let $A,B,C$ be points on the unit circle in the $xy$ plane, and $P$ be a point in space such that $PABC$ is a [trirectangular tetrahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrirectangularTetrahedron.html) with $P$ at the vertex. Find the locus of $P$ as $A,B,C$ vary on the circle.

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547717/trirectangular-tetrahedron-uniqueness-of-vertex-given-base) stackexchange post, I know that $P$ is uniquely defined for any $A,B,C$, but how would I go about finding the locus of all points $P$?

Comment: Hint: Let $h$ and $H$ be height and projection of $P$ on $xy$-plane, 1) show that $H$ is orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$ and 2) use relation of orthocenter $O$, centroid $G$ and orthocenter $H$ on [euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line) to simplify the "sum" of 3 equations: $$\small (A-H)(B-H) + h^2 = (B-H)(C-H)+h^2 + (C-H)(A-H)+h^2 = 0$$

Comment: @godlification: Since $ A,B,C $ move on a base circle do you want the locus **surface** of P? I think it would be more interesting if one of $ A,B,C $ is fixed, say C, without loss of generality.

Comment: Well, for a given A,B,C, we have that P is some height above the orthocenter, so we can turn the problem around - for a given orthocenter H, what’s the allowed height of P above it. There are formulas for OH and PH in terms of the side lengths and circumradius, so it might be possible to either get one as a function of the other or bound it in terms of the other. I suspect it’s an ellipsoid.

Comment: @Eric it is an ellipsoid, it can be proved using the relation $\overrightarrow{OH} = \overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{OC}$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: One way for constructing a  trirectangular tetrahedron  is as per comment by user  achille hui:

1. find the orthocenter of triangle (H).
2. draw a perpendicular at H on plane the triangle ABC locates, like in figure xy plane.
3. Find the mid point of one side, say AC.
4. Draw a sphere center at midpoint and crossing point A and C.
5. Use intersect command to find the intersection of the perpendicular and the sphere, this point is P which is the vertex of trirectangular tetrahedron .

Now if the triangle is equilateral, then the vertex will be I which is lower than point T(intersection of perpendicular from G and sphere based on circumcircle. If the triangle is right angled, then the orthocenter is on the circucircle , and the sphere on the circumcircle is also the one constructed using the mid point of the hypotenuse, which is the center of the circumccircl(also the sphere), that is the vertex is on circumccircle. For other types of triangle the vertex P is somewhere between I and plane xy.  Hence the locus of P seems to be an ellipsoid inscribed in the sphere on circumcircle. The formula is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

Here $b=r$, $a=r$ and $c=OI$, since $OI<r\rightarrow c<a$ the ellipsoid is oblate.